# Cannot edit single NURBS curve control points after changing its properties

Tags: edit-mode

If I do the following:

- Add a NURBS curve
- Select a control point
- Press N and change its y property to 0.0
- Repeat this step for all the control points of the NURBS curve

Then I'm unable to edit the single control point: if I select a single control point and try to move it, the whole NURBS curve with all the control points are displaced. It seems like the curve becomes a whole object whose single points cannot be modified. If instead I just change the x,y,z values of the single control points through the panel they are edited singularly.

Comment: Can you give us a screenshot? An animated GIF would be even better.

Comment: Did you by accident press the O key and turn on proportional editing? Try disabling it in the 3D view toolbar at the bottom of the screen

Comment: Yes, I had proportional editing turned on. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Hey @DuarteFarrajotaRamos... that'd make a pretty nice answer. Better get that posted before someone else does ;-)

Comment: Hehe I didn't deem it was worthy of a full answer for such a common and small problem, but I'll post it bellow. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you unintentionally pressed <kbd>O</kbd> key by accident and turned on Proportional editing.

Try disabling it in the 3D view toolbar at the bottom of the screen